# What Drools JARS are needed in a servet's WEB-INF\lib for jBPM?

Tags: servlets, jboss, drools, jbpm

I have ported a Tomcat servlet to run with JBoss 7.1 and am now trying to add jBPM support to it.  I have run the jbpm-5.4.0.Final-installer-full.zip to get JBoss/jBPM installed with Kepler (I had to patch the installer to install Kepler).  I then copied a line of code from the installer's "evaluation" sample and placed it in my servlet.  That line of code is:

```
KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
```

After adding the necessary imports I got a clean build.  I thought that I could then take the Drools run time files I found in the installer's .\runtime\lib and place them in my servlet's .\WEB-INF\lib.  However, doing this caused me to get a "Class not found" exception when I tried to execute the KnowledgeBuilder line of code.  It turns out that if I replace the JARs from the installer's .\runtime\lib with the JARS in drools-distribution-5.5.0.Final.zip (from http://www.jboss.org/drools/downloads) in my .\WEB-INF\lib I am able to execute KnowledgeBuilder line of code.

My questions are:
1) Why don't the JARs from the installer's .\runtime\lib work in the above?
2) Where can I find documentation on what all of these Drools JARs do and which ones are needed?

Thank you.
Al

Answer (score 0):

If I were to list specific Jars here, the answer would only apply to a specific version of Drools. The best way to get the correct JARs is to use Maven to build your project. That will automatically import all of the JARs that are needed.

You will usually need dependencies for drools-core and drools-compiler. Those have their own transitive dependencies.

```
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${drools.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>${drools.version}</version>
            </dependency>
```

If you use Eclipse, then you can just create a pom.xml with those dependencies in it. Open it in the Maven pom editor and the "Effective POM" tab will show you all of the required dependencies.